# Animating a fluid water fountain

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I was trying to make a water fountain and animate water flowing through it. I added the domain and inflow to the mesh but couldn't make the water flow out of the mesh/fountain. It just drops straight down from the mesh. I want to make a real life water fountain where water first comes out/up from the bottom/inside to a certain height then take up a certain area and finally fall back down.

I guess what I'm trying to say is control the direction and area of flow of the fluid. If you guys have any idea how to achieve that, any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the inflow's velocity to be positive in the Z direction. This will force the inflow's fluid up, giving you the fountain effect. Here is a bit about an example I quickly put together.

[image]

(click on the images to see a larger version)

Inflow settings (just a simple cube):

[image]

Domain settings:

[image]

Outflow plane below the fountain to "kill" all water than falls below. This is like a vacuum to "suck up" the water.

[image]

The fountain model itself is just a simple fluid obstacle.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What addon is it that gives you the quick install of addons and the calculator?

Comment: @David Both are my add-ons...the zip addon reloader is available on GitLab [here](https://gitlab.com/integrity-sg/zip_addon_reloader) with the basic usage info in the home page of the wiki. The calculator one was more just for fun, and not really intended for the public, but you are welcome to play with it if you'd like: http://pasteall.org/1140429/python. Also, I'll add a disclaimer that the calculator has not been edited in years, and I've picked up most of my Python knowledge since then, so it looked like quite a mess when I just opened it up.