# How do I animate water splash?

Tags: modeling, animation

I want to animate water splash.  All I want is to splash water from bottle to paper towel. Which method should I use ?

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: If your looking to animate water I'd recommend watching this guy's Youtube tutorial videos on water simulation to get used to the physics so you can create the effect your going for. 2.8 version https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3OGnsu16yX0 2.79 version https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xIxUZpRk4Ac

Comment: I made a possible solution, but i don't know if i'll have time to create anwser now, so i'll share link in case there was no solution and i never come back : https://www.dropbox.com/s/zjud3ihggtoiqvt/water.blend?dl=0

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134901/how-would-i-go-about-making-water-shoot-out-of-a-pipe-rather-than-just-flow-out/134906#134906 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74854/animating-a-fluid-water-fountain https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61531/jet-stream-of-water https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86599/water-spray-simulation

Comment: @softyodayoann I can't see your work in Blender(2.79) :/

Comment: @JakeG Thanks,I already watched his videos but I couldn't find anything for me :/

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I've seen these contents but I couldn't do it. Therefore I asked it again...

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86599/water-spray-simulation this one was really helpful. But I don't know how can I create  "density weight group" and change the direction of particles...

Comment: You should post a different question about it then. Describe what you did show what already have with some screenshots and where you are stuck. Link to any relevant posts and be sure to search before posting if it has been asked before.