# Volcano eruption Blender

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm currently using Blender 2.83 and I'm new to fluid simulations. I want to create a volcano eruption, using fluid. I've created my collision and used a UV sphere for where the liquid will flow from. It's currently flowing down into the volcano. I want it to go up. How do I can the direction? I want it to erupt, not flow down like a tap.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Animating a fluid water fountain](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74854/animating-a-fluid-water-fountain)

Comment: @Luciano It did, thanks. It's now coming out ball-liked. Also, it's quite thin. I have photos if you can help? Not sure how to share them on here as I'm a new user.

Comment: @Luciano I added a photo in the answer section

Comment: Hi, @ConnorE95 new information regarding your question should always be added as an [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/182350/edit) to your original post rather  than as an answer. The answer section is, as the name implies, reserved for answers to the question. Thanks!